# Is it IQ or IQ score?

Tags: word-choice, redundancy

What's the correct way to use the term ***[intelligence quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IQ)*** in a sentence?

> Jim's IQ is 130.
>   *–or–*
>   Jim's IQ score is 130.

Answer (score 5):

**It's just IQ not IQ score.**  
But note that one could score a 130 on an IQ test which, depending on the test, may or may not accurately reflect the person's real IQ.  *Score* in this case refers to the taking of the test not the quotient itself.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the test score angle. (Or, well, for mentioning it first, a whole two minutes before JeffSahol.)

Answer (score 4):

Although IQ can be measured, it's not a score, it's an index: the population average is 100, and individual IQs are compared to that.

*Jim's IQ is 130* is correct.

Comment: -1 it is not index just the result of a formula called Gaussian function. I am not a hater Andrew I just like when people are talking about Math to use the right words.

Comment: @speedyGonzales. Whatever. I could have used *ordinal scale*, I suppose [(21)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient#cite_note-20)[(22)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient#cite_note-21)[(23)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient#cite_note-22)[(24)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient#cite_note-23). But then an IQ number is an index to the person's position on that ordinal scale, isn't it?

Comment: @speedyGonzales, the real world is never quite as clear-cut as mathematicians would like. (And using "formula" and "function" in this situation seems sloppier to me than using "index" as an approximate synonym of "quotient".)

Comment: Functions are subset of formulas. People give different definitions of *index* and the most spread ones are not suitable to be used in that context. If he has given nice explanation of index before using it his answer should have been correct. It Math we have to call the theorem before using it even in USA and UK. For example we can use score and it will be perfectly correct in the context of taking the IQ test. When we are talking about tests we use scores not indexes. Will you give me link where the term approximate synonyms in English grammar are explained.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why you say that "score" is an inappropriate term. IQ is measured by giving someone a quiz. A measure of the number of questions you got right on a quiz is routinely called a "score". Granted in this case it's redundant, you would normally just say "his IQ is 87", but I don't think it's wrong to refer to an IQ as a "score".

Comment: The score in the test is not the same as the rank within the population (although I suppose the test could be engineered so it is). See Jim's answer.

Answer (score 3):

***Score*** strikes me as being redundant, since the number is a quotient, which is already part of the name. On the other hand, one might say that someone "scored" 130 on an IQ test.

Answer (score 2):

A *[quotient](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quotient)* is indicative of a number, so to also say *score* is somewhat redundant.  I would venture to guess that anyone who is familiar with *IQ* expects a number afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Many people are confusing me using IQ or IQ score. It is not a index nor score. Only people that don't know anything about Statistics(Math term) use the term IQ. The result of IQ test is based on Normal Distribution. The result of your IQ is based on Math formula that shows where is your result compared to what is considered to be normal using the Gaussian function. Well I know that so called linguists are going to crucify me, but this is not language this is Math.

Comment: Oh, but it *is* language. There might be math behind it, but when we speak of intelligence quotients, we use *language*. How the number is derived is largely irrelevant. (By the way, in English we usually use "normal distribution" rather than "Gaussian function". [Is it even a *function*, mathematically speaking?])

Comment: Where are you using normal distribution in your everyday English, I am just curious? Well it is not my business to teach you what is function. Get a book and read the definition and thing about it.

Comment: and be sure to ignore anything that is language in that book.

Comment: @speedyGonzales, I have a degree in math. I know what a function is; that's why I'm questioning whether the normal distribution is one. (Note that I said it's called that "in English", not "in everyday English". In the latter, it's called the bell curve.)